# how can I find nearest* key in a sparse python list (or dict) in O(1) time?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

I have some code where I have a number of dicts that look something like this:

```
d = {63:1, 96:2, 128:3, 192:4, 256:6, 384:9, 480:12, 511:14}
```

These are used with another lookup key to do threshold checks: where we want to find the value associated with the closest dict key that is higher than our lookup key.  So for the dict above, a search for any `k <=63` would return `1`, a search on any `k >63 && k <=96` would return `2`, and so on.

The code I received did a simple walk through the dict k/v pairs, as so:

```
for k,v in d.items():    ## keys are in strictly increasing order
    if lookup_key > k:   ## walk up the dict, are we still smaller than the dict key?
        rc = v
return rc
```

This works, but as it "walks up" the dictionary keys, the performance isn't great.  It does a compare for every k,v pair in the dict as well as a (re)assignment for however many of the keys are smaller, so we end up with somewhere between O(n) and O(2n) operations.

This lookup gets called trillions of times in the simulations I'm running, so I'm trying to find a way to make this O(1).  The brute force way to do this is just convert this mapping dictionary into a flat <s>array</s> list, where I replicate all the intermediate values, and end up with a direct table with the number of entries equal to the largest key in the dict, and each index would map directly to the return value.   So if I had a source dict like this:

```
example = {2:12, 4:17, 7:21, 8:50}
```

I could convert that into a list such as:

```
        Idx =   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
directTable = [12, 12, 12, 17, 17, 21, 21, 21, 50]
```

This is nice because it obviously runs in O(1) time, but it requires doing the work to pre-build this and the state to store it.  In my *particular* case I can live with this restriction because the max size of the direct table isn't too big, but it got me wondering if there's some other way to do this that doesn't involve flattening/explicitly building out a big array.  I found [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) which would help if the dictionary had a lot of keys, but in my case most of these dicts have in the range of 3-10 keys.  So even if I could do an O(logN) search, on a short dictionary that might still be 3-4 operations, which compared to O(1) and run trillions of times is a lot of clock cycles.  ;-)

So again, I guess my specific problem is solved, but is there some super fancy pythonic magic I'm unaware of that would let me do this even more elegantly?

Comment: You should first ask yourself: Does a O(1) solution even exist here? The only way for such a solution to exist is if you can calculate the "nearest" key from the "lookup" key with arithmetic or bitwise operations.

Comment: It looks like all of your keys are one of the following patterns: `2^n-1`, `2^n+2^(n-1)`, and `2^n` for some value of `n`. Is this set of formulas exhaustive of all of your real keys? If not, what other patterns are there? You may be able to take advantage of these power-of-two patterns to calculate the required value in `O(1)`.

Comment: If you think you’ll see the same values for an argument, you could use `functools.memoize` in front of binary search. That would give you O(1) performance on cache hits.

Comment: If I had to pick between optimizing trillions of checks vs caching a O(1) lookup solution in memory, I'd definitely pick the latter.

Comment: Is O(log n) good enough? You can find the smallest-greater-than or biggest-less-than in a balanced binary search tree in O(log n) time.